# Retrieving Child Node Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m trying to recover the data on an specific child node. Here is the structure:

```
RESTAURANTS
    KTNfWKLD0isCsrpys
        name: “McDonalds”
        loc: “LA”
    KTNfWKLD0isCsrpys
        name: “KFC”
        loc: “LV”
```

Code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("RESTAURANTS".observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        for names in snapshot.children {
            self.loadingNames.append(names.key)
        }

    })
```

I tried this but I only get the children names like this `[“name”,”loc"]`, but I want to get the names like this `[“McDonalds”,”KFC”]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("RESTAURANTS".observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

    if let name = snapshot.value?["name"] as? String {
        self.loadingNames.append(name)
    }
})
```

**Edit:** change observer `observeSingleEventOfType` to `observeEventType`

Comment: It only gets the first restaurant name as string. i want to make it [String] (array of strings) to get the 2 restaurant name. Is there a way so i can loop it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can append the names to your string array like that:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("RESTAURANTS".observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  for names in snapshot.children {
    if let name = names as? FIRDataSnapshot  {
      let nameValue = name.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
      self.loadingNames.append(nameValue)
    }
  }  
})
```